# PHPass returns error

Tags: php, phpass

In my functions file I have this code:

```
function password($password, $dbpassword = false){
    if($dbpassword){
        $password = mysqli_real_escape_string($GLOBALS["mysqli"], $_POST["$dbpassword"]);
        if(empty($password))
            $password = mysqli_real_escape_string($GLOBALS["mysqli"], $_GET["$dbpassword"]);
            if(empty($password))
                return false;
    }
    $hasher = new PasswordHash(8, false);
    if (strlen($password) > 72)
        return false;
    else{
        if($dbpassword){
            $check = $hasher->CheckPassword($password, $dbpassword);
            if ($check)
                return true;
            else
                return false;
        }else{
            $hash = $hasher->HashPassword($password);
            if (strlen($hash) >= 20) 
                return $hash;
            else
                return false;
        }
    }
}
```

and in another file (with includes to functions and to the PHPASS php file) I have this code:

```
$pass = password("Vlad");
if(password("Vlad", $pass)){
    echo 11;
}else{
    echo 22;
}
```

It returns 22. Why is that?

Comment: Step through your code and debug it. If you don't have a debugger print output next to each decision tree until you find which `return false` is causing the problem

Comment: Why not use built-in PHP `password_hash()` and `password_verify()` functions? You also should probably not be using `$GLOBALS`, as this poor programming practice. If you need your `mysqli` object/connection, you should pass it to the function.

Answer (score 0):

When you call your `password` function with a second variable that is not `NULL`, it will return `false` unless a `POST` or `GET` variable is set when you call your page.

The name of that `POST` or `GET` variable needs to be the password hash of the password you hashed the first time you used your function as you are using:

```
$_POST["$dbpassword"]
```

or

```
$_GET["$dbpassword"]
```

I doubt that the name of the form-field in your form is changing constantly so that would explain why the function always returns `false` the second time you call it.